# List of days between start and end dates

Tags: perl, datetime

Im trying to get each individual date between a start and an end date in Perl. I had initially done it for 7 days using the code below :

```
use Time::ParseDate;  
my $newdate;
my $newtime;
my @dates = ();

my $newtime->[0] = parsedate($start_datetime);
my $newdate->[0] = strftime("%Y-%m-%d",localtime($newtime->[0]));
push(@dates, $newdate->[0]);
my $newtime->[1] = parsedate($newdate->[0]) + (1 * 24 * 60 * 60);
my $newdate->[1] = strftime("%Y-%m-%d",localtime($newtime->[1]));
push(@dates, $newdate->[1]);
my $newtime->[2] = parsedate($newdate->[1]) + (1 * 24 * 60 * 60);
my $newdate->[2] = strftime("%Y-%m-%d",localtime($newtime->[2]));
push(@dates, $newdate->[2]);
my $newtime->[3] = parsedate($newdate->[2]) + (1 * 24 * 60 * 60);
my $newdate->[3] = strftime("%Y-%m-%d",localtime($newtime->[3]));
push(@dates, $newdate->[3]);
my $newtime->[4] = parsedate($newdate->[3]) + (1 * 24 * 60 * 60);
my $newdate->[4] = strftime("%Y-%m-%d",localtime($newtime->[4]));
push(@dates, $newdate->[4]);
my $newtime->[5] = parsedate($newdate->[4]) + (1 * 24 * 60 * 60);
my $newdate->[5] = strftime("%Y-%m-%d",localtime($newtime->[5]));
push(@dates, $newdate->[5]);
my $newtime->[6] = parsedate($newdate->[5]) + (1 * 24 * 60 * 60);
my $newdate->[6] = strftime("%Y-%m-%d",localtime($newtime->[6]));
push(@dates, $newdate->[6]);
my $newtime->[7] = parsedate($newdate->[6]) + (1 * 24 * 60 * 60);
my $newdate->[7] = strftime("%Y-%m-%d",localtime($newtime->[7]));
push(@dates, $newdate->[7]);
```

but realized that it should be able to work for any number of days.
so I tried the loop below but it didnt quite work for me

```
my $newdate;
my $newtime;
my @dates = ();
my $start_date = substr($start_datetime, 0, 10) ; 
$start_date =~ s/-//gi;  
my $end_date = substr($end_datetime, 0, 10) ;
$end_date =~ s/-//gi;

my $days = yyyymmdd_to_rata_die($end_date) - yyyymmdd_to_rata_die($start_date);
my $newtime->[0] = parsedate($xml->{action_content}->{start_date});
my $newdate->[0] = strftime("%Y-%m-%d",localtime($newtime->[0]));
push(@dates, $newdate->[0]);
for(my $x=1;$x<$days;$x++)
{
  my $newtime->[$x] = parsedate($newdate->[$x-1]) + (1 * 24 * 60 * 60);
  my $newdate->[$x] = strftime("%Y-%m-%d",localtime($newtime->[$x]));
  push(@dates, $newdate->[$x]);
}
```

I got the function below from a question here on Stackoverflow

```
sub yyyymmdd_to_rata_die
{
    use integer;
    my ( $y, $m, $d ) = $_[0] =~ /\A([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})\z/
    or return;

    my $adj;

    if ( $m <= 2 ) 
    {
        $y -= ( $adj = ( 14 - $m ) / 12 );
        $m += 12 * $adj;
    }
    elsif ( $m > 14 ) 
    {
        $y += ( $adj = ( $m - 3 ) / 12 );
        $m -= 12 * $adj;
    }

    $d += ( $m * 367 - 1094 ) / 12 + $y % 100 * 1461 / 4 + ( $y / 100 * 36524 + $y / 400 ) - 306;
}
```

any assistance will be greatly apreciated

EDIT:
$start_datetime = "2014-09-01 00:00:00";
$end_datetime = "2014-09-07 23:59:59";

I need all the days in between the start and end date ie. 
2014-09-01 
2014-09-02 
2014-09-03 
2014-09-04 
2014-09-05 
2014-09-06 
2014-09-07

Comment: Please give an example of the input and corresponding output that you require.

Comment: Your code suggests that you're using `XML::Simple`. If you are then I strongly advise that you move to something else, as working with it is anything but *simple*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend that you use the [`Time::Piece`](https://metacpan.org/module/Time::Piece) module. It shouldn't need installing as it has been a core module since version 10 of Perl 5.

It would look like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Time::Piece;

print days_between('2014-01-01', '2014-12-01'), "\n";

sub days_between {
  my ($start, $end) = map Time::Piece->strptime($_, '%Y-%m-%d'), @_;
  ($end - $start)->days;
}
```

**output**

```
334
```

---

**Update**

I apologize. I misunderstood your requirements and thought you wanted the *number of days* between the two dates. This program prints a *list* of all the dates between and including the two limits. If called in scalar context it will provide the *number* of days in the list, as before.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Time::Piece;
use Time::Seconds qw/ ONE_DAY /;

printf "%d days:\n", scalar days_from_to('2014-09-01 00:00:00', '2014-09-07 23:59:59');

print "$_\n" for days_from_to('2014-09-01 00:00:00', '2014-09-07 23:59:59');

sub days_from_to {

   my @limits = map /(\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d)/, @_;
   @limits = map Time::Piece->strptime($_, '%Y-%m-%d'), @limits;

   my @dates = ( $limits[0] );
   push @dates, $dates[-1] + ONE_DAY while $dates[-1] < $limits[-1];   

   map $_->ymd, @dates;
}
```

**output**

```
7 days:
2014-09-01
2014-09-02
2014-09-03
2014-09-04
2014-09-05
2014-09-06
2014-09-07
```

---

**Update**

If a more critical regex is required that will reject strings like `0123-45-67` then you can use this

```
my $date_re = qr/(?:
   (?: (?:19|20)[0-9][0-9] ) -
   (?:
      (?: 0?[469] | 11 ) -
      (?: 0?[1-9] | [12][0-9] | 30 )
   |
      (?: 0?[13578] | 1[02] ) -
      (?: 0?[1-9] | [12][0-9] | 3[01] )
   |
      (?: 0?2 ) -
      (?: 0?[1-9] | [12][0-9] )
   )
)/x;
```

which will accept dates between 1900 and 2099, and makes sure that the day of the month is valid for that month. The only proviso is that it will allow 29 February in any year.

Or you may prefer to use [`Regexp::Common::time`](https://metacpan.org/module/Regexp::Common::time) like this

```
use Regexp::Common qw/ time /;

my $date_re = $RE{time}{strftime}{-pat => '%Y-%m-%d'};
```

but this has the same issue with 29 February.

The subroutine will look like this

```
sub days_from_to {

   my @limits = map /($date_re)/, @_;

   @limits = map Time::Piece->strptime($_, '%Y-%m-%d'), @limits;

   my @dates = ( $limits[0] );
   push @dates, $dates[-1] + ONE_DAY while $dates[-1] < $limits[-1];   

   map $_->ymd, @dates;
}
```

Comment: @ladyT: You're welcome. Note that the regex removes everything except the first thing that looks like a date. That means the time is unnecessary, but you could pass a whole log line, or even multi-line text, as long as the first date in it is the one you want. But beware of stuff like `0000-99-99` which will confuse it completely!

Answer (score 0):

You can make your life a lot easier by using something like [Time::Piece](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Piece);

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use Time::Piece;
use Time::Seconds;

my $fmt = '%Y-%m-%d';

my $start_date = '2014-09-08';
my $days = 30;

my @dates;
my $date = Time::Piece->strptime($start_date, $fmt);

foreach (1 .. $days) {
  push @dates, $date;
  $date += ONE_DAY;
}

say $_ for @dates;
```

**Update:** Looks like [Borodin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25725509/7231) uses a very similar approach and deals with the inputs and required outputs that you have added to your question.

Comment: It looks like the parameters are a start and end date, and they include the time fields, like `2014-09-07 23:59:59` so `strptime` will raise a *garbage at end of string* warning unless it is trimmed.